# ActiveAndroid where with a "in" clause

Tags: activeandroid

I would like to know if it is possible and how I could do a where clause in ActiveAndroid with a "IN" clause.

For example, I would like do do something like this:

new Select().from(Table).where("id in ?", list).execute()

Answer (score 13):

The query should work almost as is - ActiveAndroid reduces your SELECT to SQL anyway.

For example, the following LIKE query works for me:

```
public static List<Record> search(String searchTerm) {
    return new Select().from(Record.class)
            .where("Data LIKE ?", new String[]{'%' + searchTerm + '%'})
            .orderBy("Name ASC")
            .execute();
}
```

where search term is '%searchTerm%'

If you are having difficulty, you can query the DB directly, ie:

```
    mRecordList = SQLiteUtils.rawQuery(Record.class,
            "SELECT * from Records where Data LIKE ?",
            new String[]{'%' + searchTerm + '%'});
            */
```

Comment: What to do if we need to fetch records with respect to offests. Currently only the querying the DB directly is working for me.

Comment: do you want to mark the answer as correct one day @SalmanKhakwani ? ;)

Comment: I would love to! But this isn't my question, dear.

Answer (score 1):

new Select().from(Table).where("id in (1,2)").execute()

Answer (score 0):

use this link for IN clause in activeandroid. Its bit difficult but check the answer given by **jlhonora**. it worked for me

https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/392